# event listner  ajax Jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Js and Ajax. I am calling a page through ajax (using jquery). the called page has a button. On button click, i need an alert box. But the event listner is not acting on the button click.

```
    function setUpClickHandler() {
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById('sideLink1'), "click", onsideLinkClicked1, false);
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById('EnrollButtonClick11'), "click", onEnrollButtonClick11, false);
}

function onsideLinkClicked1(e) {
    $('#CrousalLoad').load('crousal1.html');
}
function onEnrollButtonClick11(e) {
    alert("hello");   
}
```

crousal1.html is the loaded page and "EnrollButtonClick11" is the button id inside the page. Is there anything I am missing here. Plz add comments for any clarifications as I am struck here. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: It's very simple with jQuery click - http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Why you dont use it using JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using jQuery you can skip that in just do this.

```
$("#sideLink1").click(function (){
alert('hello');//you do it directly in the function
onEnrollButtonClick11(); //or call a function from here.
})
```

Source:

http://api.jquery.com/click/
says the same thing.

Comment: click on "#sideLink1" is loading the page and button is inside this page. "#EnrollButtonClick11" is the id of the button and alert is needed on clicking this button. The above code is not working in my scenario :(

Comment: Oh I see, I'm pretty sure the `on()` will do what you're trying to do since the element is dynamically created.  `$("#EnrollButtonClick11" ).on('click', onEnrollbuttonClick11);`

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because the button you are registering a click to with the id of EnrollButtonClick11 doesn't exist on the page at that moment. Since you are using jQuery try something like $('body').on('click', 'EnrollButtonClick11', onEnrollButtonClick11);

Comment: function setUpClickHandler() {
$('body').on('click', 'EnrollButtonClick11', onEnrollButtonClick11);
}
Is this what u meant ?